# What is inside first <> brackets

Tags: javascript

I want to get content inside the first angle brackets in a string, like

```
str = 'testing <i need this> yes... and <i dont need this>';  
str1 = '<i also need this> where r u?';
```

I want
'i need this' from str
'i also need this' from str1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A regex is a good way to do this:

```
var regex = /<(.*?)>/;
var match = regex.exec(str);
var insideBrackets = match.length > 1 && match[1];
```

Edit: switched from `+` to `*` as it's true the brackets might contain nothing.

Edit2: BIlly is correct, it needs to be non-greedy, otherwise in your first `str` it will return everything between the first `<` and the very last `>`. Thanks BIlly. If it was me I'd probably go with `/<([^>]*)>/` to be explicit in what brackets I'm interested in.

Comment: I think regex should be greedy like this `/<(.+?)>/`

Comment: @BIlly Does `?` signify greedy in JavaScript regexes? I thought regexes were greedy by default and `?` turned off greediness? I'm off to research :) If in doubt, possibly a more explicit regex such as `/<([^>]+)>/` would be better.

Comment: Also I think `*` should be used instead of `+`

Comment: @BIlly -- I think `?` turns off greediness in JS as well, according to this site anyway: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml : `? directly following a quantifier makes the quantifier non-greedy (makes it match minimum instead of maximum of the interval defined).`

Comment: Yes - you are right, `?` makes in un-greedy, my mistake. However, I think that is what is needed right?

Comment: @BIlly -- yeah, non-greediness is actually what we needed. You were correct, I fixed my answer.